# UIImagePickerController not full screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

Since the iOS7 upgrade, I have a weird behaviour of the `UIImagePickerController`. In this application I am using the `UIImagePickerController` with a `cameraOverlayView`.

In iOS6 I called the `UIImagePickerController` using the following code:

```
_picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

if ([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear]) {
    _picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    _picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
    _picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
    _picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    _picker.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    _picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
    _picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    _overlayViewController = [[OverlayViewController alloc] init];
    _overlayViewController.picker = _picker;
    _overlayViewController.frameSize = self.frameSize;
    _overlayViewController.delegate = self;
    _picker.cameraOverlayView = _overlayViewController.view;
}
else {
    _picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

}
_picker.delegate = self;
```

Where the `OverlayViewController` is an `UIViewController`, with a transparent background which draws some custom controls on screen.

[image]

But now in iOS 7 the camera is drawn through the statusbar and a black bar appears beneath the live camera view.

I can solve this by applying a `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation` to the `cameraViewTransform` property of the `UIImagePickerController`, but why is this like this?

Comment: Would love to hear if you are able to fix it without transform?

Comment: Have you fixed the issue?

Comment: @Wim Haanstra Hi..did u got through this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 7, by default UIViewController views take up the entire screen area including the status bar.

```
wantsFullScreenLayout
```

is deprecated and ignored. In some cases, this fix works (in the view controller class):

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)]) {
    [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
}
```

In other cases, it's a bit more complicated. It's late here, so see how you go with it. Helpful things to note - in a UIViewController, the following code will give the correct statusbar height on both iOS 6 and iOS 7, should it come to having to align things using CGRect math:

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
            statusBarHeight = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.width;
        } else {
            statusBarHeight = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;
        }
```

And then don't forget that in Interface Builder, there are the new "iOS 6 delta" adjustments that allow you to design for iOS 7 and then use offsets to correct for iOS 6.

Anyhow, let me know how you go.

Comment: The first suggestion does not appear to be doing anything. Also tried applying it to the _picker, but that doesn't work either.

The second one indeed gives me the correct statusbar height, but it seems that is not the problem, because the "image" of the camera is still to small (not high enough to fill the full screen).

Comment: What's the hardware that you're using?

Comment: On another investigative path, you could install Reveal and see if it gives you more insight into the problem. http://bit.ly/183QpvK

Comment: I am using iOS7 on an iPhone 5.

Comment: Same problem over here...would like to hear for solution.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the issue, based on a few other SO threads and such, is that UIImagePickerController does not do what we'd expect in terms of managing the status bar via `[UIViewController -prefersStatusBarHidden]`.

This means you either have to disable view controller status bar management entirely, via plist, or figure out a way to get UIImagePickerController to do what we want. On the assumption that you're not looking for the former, I can say I've had success in the latter by putting the picker in a wrapper controller that does what I want (but fall back to your previous code if you still need to detect/support iOS6):

```
@interface PickerContainer : UIViewController

@property ( nonatomic, weak ) UIImagePickerController* picker;

@end

@implementation PickerContainer

- (void) setPicker: (UIImagePickerController*) picker
{
    [self addChildViewController: picker];
    [picker didMoveToParentViewController: self];

    self->_picker = picker;
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.picker.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview: self.picker.view];
}

// Will have no effect in ios6 -- see [-init] for that option
- (BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden { return YES; }

- (id) init
{
    if ( ! ( self = [super init] ) ) return nil;

    if ( detectThatThisIsIos6() ) self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you, scaled camera, you will have a black bar at the bottom but it will get overlayed by tool bar
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15803947