# Black view at bottom when using custom camera overlay view (UIImagePickerController)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6, xcode5

I want to use custom camera overlay view. Below is the code for it.

```
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
self.imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
self.imagePicker.toolbarHidden = YES;
self.imagePicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
self.imagePicker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = [self cameraOverlayView];
```

The issue is there is a black background at bottom and I don't get from where it is coming.
What is wrong in code?

Comment: Its Working fine in both ios6 and 7.. in which device you have tested?

Comment: @Virussmca I am running in iOS 6 and its not working for me.

Comment: Is something in [self cameraOverlayView] ? method ? i have commented on that line, and its working fine with ios 6 .

Comment: @Virussmca it returns custom overlay view with 3 button.

Comment: I dont know whats wrong with you, i have run same code and its working.

Comment: @Virussmca OMG. It is not a toolbar but a black background but its not mine. It is at bottom and have same size as toolbar. It seems from default camera view. Have you ever seen it?

Comment: Yes. that is not toolbar. check at least before posting question.

Comment: @Virussmca Sorry for that. Do you know how to handle with that?

Comment: Yes. you can set cameraViewTransform to full screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIImagePickerController doesn't fill screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674375/uiimagepickercontroller-doesnt-fill-screen)

Answer (score 3):

Try cameraViewTransform for full screen.

```
    CGFloat camScaleup = 2;
    imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(imagePicker.cameraViewTransform, camScaleup, camScaleup);
```

Comment: It works but cannot understand it. Can you describe your logic of how and why you use aspect ratio to calculate scale?

Comment: Sorry Logic is not created by me, i have just refere you.

Comment: It does not give correct scale value. Still there is a small black background.

Comment: The camera's image itself is not large enough and needs to be scaled to fit the space.

Comment: @Akash: check updated answer, that is the maximum camera screen you can show with uiimagePicker.

Comment: Why 2? You could have taken 4.0/3.0 i.e. 1.33.

Comment: its direct value , removing calculation.

Comment: Sorry but this does not fix the issue. This property is to change the zoom of the camera and not to scale up the live view of the camera