# UIImagePickerController using iOS 8 cameraViewTransform isn't scaling

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I have previously solved a camera overlay issue: [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674375/uiimagepickercontroller-doesnt-fill-screen)

```
CGSize screenBounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;

CGFloat cameraAspectRatio = 4.0f/3.0f;

CGFloat camViewHeight = screenBounds.width * cameraAspectRatio;
CGFloat scale = screenBounds.height / camViewHeight;

self.picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, (screenBounds.height - camViewHeight) / 2.0);
self.picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.picker.cameraViewTransform, scale, scale);
```

but now in iOS 8 there's a black bar a the bottom of the live photo preview again. so scaling like this no longer works:

```
self.picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.picker.cameraViewTransform, scale, scale);
```

I'm not able to scale the cameraViewTransform. Any ideas on how to get this to work with iOS 8? Has this been deprecated?

Comment: are you aware about changes in screen bound ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150359/is-uiscreen-mainscreen-bounds-size-becoming-orientation-dependent-in-ios8

Comment: @Jageen: I am facing exactly the same issue as djburdick. I was using the same code to scale the UIImagePickerController in iPhone 5 size device. But, the same fails in iOS 8. Keeping the changes regarding screen bound in iOS 8 in mind, what should be the change in above code snippet? I am not able to figure out. Please help.

Comment: @djburdick: did you get any solution for this issue in iOS 8? Please let me know. It will help me a lot!!

Comment: Any solutions on this please share?

Comment: I just posted about this problem, which appears to be a bug in iOS 8.
My solution was to make attach a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` to the custom overlay and manually handle the zoom.
See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30288950/2397253

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 8 you no longer need to scale if you want to fill the screen. So the unique thing you have to do is to comment the assignment:

//self.picker.cameraViewTransform

That is to say, self.picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0) conforms to self.picker.view.frame automatically.

In conclusion, the work is already done for you by UIImagePickerController.

Comment: Is it true really? I have not checked it. But is it working without the transform?

Comment: Without the transform, in 8.2, I get a failure to correctly rotate the preview correctly, which is far worse than the black bar problem.

Comment: Where did Tony Adams see anything regarding rotation within the question? You should assess the response for the question. This method really works conforming to the original question.