# UIImagePickerController's cameraViewTransform property does not scale on iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, ios8

I am displaying UIImagePickerController in a landscape manner using custom overlay. Because of the camera aspect ratio in iPhone 5 and 5S, I had to scale the live preview of the image using "cameraViewTransform".

```
            CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

            float cameraAspectRatio = 4.0 / 3.0;
            float imageWidth = floorf(screenSize.width * cameraAspectRatio);
            float scale = ceilf((screenSize.height / imageWidth) * 10.0) / 10.0;

            m_objImagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, (screenSize.height - imageWidth) / 2.0);

            m_objImagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(m_objImagePickerController.cameraViewTransform, scale, scale);
```

This was inspired from this post : [UIImagePickerController doesn't fill screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674375/uiimagepickercontroller-doesnt-fill-screen)

It worked perfectly fine till the arrival of iOS 8. **Seems like the scaling of cameraViewTransform is not working in iOS 8**. But the translation is taking effect. Because of this, I can see significant black bars in live camera preview. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

**Please note that I have not switched to Xcode 6 as of now. This is with Xcode 5.1.1 only.** I have to move my application to app store in few days. Then I will switch to Xcode 6. Before that, I don't want to take any chances.

**If anybody faced this issue, please help. I am not finding any solution for iOS 8.**

Comment: Is anyone having any workaround or solution for this? Please help.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Is there any solution to this. I have tried number of things scaling, translation on the cameraViewTransform but nothing works!

Comment: Have you found any thing? Please share your solution...

Comment: No. Not yet. I am planning to move to Xcode 6. But I don't have any clue as of now

Comment: see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734962/uiimagepickercontroller-using-ios-8-cameraviewtransform-isnt-scaling