# UIImagePickerController's cameraViewTransform is ignoring 'scaling' and 'translation' on iOS 10 beta

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, ios10, xcode8-beta6

I have been using below code to scale my UIImagePickerController's live preview to fill the entire screen. This worked perfectly till now. Before few days, I installed iOS 10 beta 7 on an iPhone 5 and it doesn't scale anymore. I can see black patch at the bottom of UIImagePickerController's view. Seems like `cameraViewTransform` is ignoring the `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` and `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation` calls.

**This is how I initiate my camera controller. I have set both "allowsEditing" and "showsCameraControls" to 'NO' in order to provide my own custom overlay view.**

```
objImagePickerController =[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

objImagePickerController.delegate = self;
objImagePickerController.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
objImagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
objImagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
objImagePickerController.showsCameraControls= NO;
```

**This is what I use to scale the camera live preview.**

```
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
float screenHeight= MAX(screenSize.height, screenSize.width);
float screenWidth= MIN(screenSize.height, screenSize.width);

float cameraAspectRatio = 4.0 / 3.0;
float imageWidth = floorf(screenWidth * cameraAspectRatio);
float scale = ceilf((screenHeight / imageWidth) * 10.0) / 10.0;

objImagePickerController.cameraViewTransform= CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
```

**This is how I add the camera view as a subview instead of traditional modal presentation method, to suit my own requirements.**

```
 [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]addSubview:objImagePickerController.view];
```

**screenshot from iPhone 5s running on iOS 10 beta 8**

[image]

**screenshot from iPhone 5s running on iOS 8.2**

[image]

As noticeable from the above screenshots, the `cameraViewTransform` doesn't respect the `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` in iOS 10 beta.

Did anybody else face this issue? This is a really weird behavior appearing in iOS 10 beta OS. I am unable to find a workaround for this. Please advise.

NOTE:: objImagePickerController is an instance of UIImagePickerController.

Comment: why do you give two different objs to cameraViewTransform ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri: Sorry, I didn't get you!

Comment: Please note that this transform affects only live preview images but nothing else. I don't think live preview images are available on iphone 5.

Comment: No, this is not live preview. "cameraViewTransform" refers to the transform property of UIImagePickerController's view.

Comment: I'm not sure, that's what it says in the documentation. There is a similar question asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734962/uiimagepickercontroller-using-ios-8-cameraviewtransform-isnt-scaling

Comment: Not sure if that solution works or not. I will give a try.

Comment: An update- iOS 10 beta 8 is already released and the same issue persists there too.

Comment: I'm experiencing this bug too and submitted it to https://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: looks like the GM release has the same issue... great..

Comment: Sad news!! So, any workaround for this?

Comment: nope ive tried every different way to call cameraViewTransform nothing works, i suppose we wait to see if they fix it, or have to change our custom views to accommodate the black bar, for > ios 10

Answer (score 7):

Strangely it only allows us to transform it **after** the presentation was completed.

Example:

```
self.presentViewController(
        self.imagePicker,
        animated: true,
        completion: {
            let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
            let ratio: CGFloat = 4.0 / 3.0
            let cameraHeight: CGFloat = screenSize.width * ratio
            let scale: CGFloat = screenSize.height / cameraHeight

            self.imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, (screenSize.height - cameraHeight) / 2.0)
            self.imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.imagePicker.cameraViewTransform, scale, scale)
        }
    )
```

This code will transform the camera view to match the screen size.

Note that this is a workaround. It works, but the user will see it resizing upon presentation.

Comment: This worked for me by adding it to my cameraIsReadyNotification method.

Comment: Doesn't work when you change imagePicker source to "UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary" and then back to "UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera"

Answer (score 5):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40561561/5537752), this issue has been fixed in iOS 10.2 and you can use the `cameraViewTransform` property before presenting the camera again.

Comment: Ohh really? I will definitely test it on latest beta version

Comment: Works in iOS 10.2.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved by delaying set cameraViewTransform after camera e AVCaptureSessionDidStartRunningNotification is raised:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(cameraIsReadyNotification:) name:AVCaptureSessionDidStartRunningNotification object:nil];
```

-

```
- (void)cameraIsReadyNotification:(NSNotification *)notification  
 {  
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{  
          float scale = ceilf((screenHeight / imageWidth) * 10.0) / 10.0;

          objImagePickerController.cameraViewTransform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
          });  
  }
```

Comment: So, is it working fine on iOS 10? When does this notification event gets fired?

Comment: Yes, in my case. The only bad is that the change is visible to the user like a flick effect.

Comment: Ohh okay. Hope that's a minor flickering

Comment: Doesn't work when you change imagePicker source to "UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary" and then back to "UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem earlier in IOS 9.3 also. Here is the code i used

```
//transform values for full screen support
#define CAMERA_TRANSFORM_X 1
#define CAMERA_TRANSFORM_Y 1.12412    

        if (IS_IPAD)
            CGAffineTransformScale(objImagePickerController.cameraViewTransform, CAMERA_TRANSFORM_X,  CAMERA_TRANSFORM_Y);
        else if (IS_IPHONE_5_Land||IS_IPHONE_4_Land||IS_IPHONE_6_Land||IS_IPHONE_6_PLUS_Land)
        {
            objImagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 2, 2);
        }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, for me, my existing code works fine till the latest 9.x.x iOS version. Only the problem comes with iOS 10. I tried your code but that doesn't help me either.

Comment: Ok just checking what i can add into it. I'm also checking various blogs and finding this issue for 10.7 and 10.8

Comment: Yes, exactly. When I initially tested this, it did work in iOS 10 beta 1, 2 and 3. But later, it surprisingly doesn't work since the arrival of iOS 10 beta 7.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in my augmented reality application and finally solved it by using **AVFoundation** framework instead of  **UIImagePickerController**. It seems that `cameraViewTransform` no longer works on iOS 10.

The code below worked for me. Add the function to your UIViewController subclass and call it.

```
- (BOOL) initCamera {

    AVCaptureSession *captureSesion = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    if ([captureSesion canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh]) {
        [captureSesion setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    AVCaptureDevice *camera = nil;
    NSArray<AVCaptureDevice*>* devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    // Select back camera
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
        if ([device position]==AVCaptureDevicePositionBack) {
            camera = device;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (camera == nil) {
        // Back camera not found.
        return false;
    }

    AVCaptureStillImageOutput *imageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc]init];
    [imageOutput setOutputSettings: @{AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG}];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc]initWithDevice:camera error: nil];

    if (![captureSesion canAddInput:deviceInput] || ![captureSesion canAddOutput:imageOutput]) {
        return false;
    }
    [captureSesion addInput:deviceInput];
    [captureSesion addOutput:imageOutput];

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *layer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc]initWithSession:captureSesion];

    // "Aspect Fill" is suitable for fullscreen camera.
    layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    layer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    layer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];
    [captureSesion startRunning];

    return true;
}
```

The most important thing is to use `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill`. With this configuration, the camera view fills the container view keeping its original aspect ratio.

Don't forget to import the framework:)

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```