# Imagepicker overlay not display in fullscreen only in ios 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10

I am using Imagepicker overlay to capture photos. In iOS 9 my code works fine, but when I run my code on iOS 10 it shows a space at the bottom which is not displayed on iOS 9 . I tried to solve it but I am not able to do it.

Here is my code that generates the issue:

```
- (void)openCamerawithOption :(UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode)camType
{
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {

        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
            [self createImagePicker:camType];
        }]];
    }
}

-(void)createImagePicker :(UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode)camType
{
    if (!imagePickerController) {
        imagePickerController = [[NonRotatableImagePickerController alloc] init];
    }
    //[imagePickerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height+(iOS7?0:20.0))];
    [APPSINGLETON setBorder:imagePickerController.view color:[UIColor redColor]];

    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
    imagePickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 60.0;

    if (iOS7) {
        CGSize screenBounds = APPDELEGATE.screenSize;
        CGFloat cameraAspectRatio = 4.0f/3.0f;
        CGFloat camViewHeight = screenBounds.width * cameraAspectRatio;
        CGFloat scale = screenBounds.height / camViewHeight;
        imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, (screenBounds.height - camViewHeight) / 2.0);
        imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform, scale, scale);
    } else {
        float cameraAspectRatio = 4.0 / 3.0;
        float imageWidth = floorf(APPDELEGATE.screenSize.width * cameraAspectRatio);
        float scale = ceilf(((APPDELEGATE.screenSize.height+20.0) / imageWidth) * 10.0) / 10.0;
        imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
    }

    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString )kUTTypeMovie, (NSString )kUTTypeImage, nil];
    imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = camType;
    imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
    imagePickerController.toolbar.hidden=YES;
    imagePickerController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    // not all devices have two cameras or a flash so just check here
    if ([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear])
    {
        imagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
    }
    else
    {
        imagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    }

    if ([UIImagePickerController isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice:imagePickerController.cameraDevice])
    {
        imagePickerController.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto;
    }

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(presentPicker) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}

-(void)presentPicker
{
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
    imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = transparentView;
}
```

Here is the screenshot
[image]

*Update*:

```
self.presentViewController(
        self.imagePicker,
        animated: true,
        completion: {
            let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
            let ratio: CGFloat = 4.0 / 3.0
            let cameraHeight: CGFloat = screenSize.width * ratio
            let scale: CGFloat = screenSize.height / cameraHeight

            self.imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, (screenSize.height - cameraHeight) / 2.0)
            self.imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.imagePicker.cameraViewTransform, scale, scale)
        }
    )

This solution from below is working for me except when I rotate the device the same issue returns.
```

[UIImagePickerController's cameraViewTransform is ignoring 'scaling' and 'translation' on iOS 10 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39124794/uiimagepickercontrollers-cameraviewtransform-is-ignoring-scaling-and-transla%3E)

Comment: Seems it's ios10 bug. Check this board <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39124794/uiimagepickercontrollers-cameraviewtransform-is-ignoring-scaling-and-transla>

Comment: @AndrewVeresov your solution works for first load but when i rotate  the screen then same issue coming again can you guide me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@chirag shah I did not found great solution for imagePicker transform in ios10. I just omitted imagepicker from my ios 10 project and use AVCaptureSession with video gravity AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill for AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer object. It's work perfectly.

Comment: I need to changed lot of thing so i cannot change the ImagePickerOverlay to AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

Comment: Your comment is working for me that why i accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

What is transparentView in your presentPicker method? Try setting it's frame like this:

```
transparentView.frame = imagePickerController.view.bounds;
imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = transparentView;
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I faced same problem. As I couldn't find a proper solution, I just transformed the view's ty like

```
CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, sizeMissingAtBottom);
imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = translate;
```

You can then `CGAffineTransformScale` the translate if needed.

Comment: I checked your answer