# UIImagePickerController cameraViewTransform is not working in iOS 10

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, ios10, ios-camera

i have implemented camera overlay view in my application. camera overlay view working good in iOS 9. but iOS 10 cameraViewTransform not working how to resolve this problem. please guide me. Thanks

my working code

```
CGSize screenBounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
CGFloat cameraAspectRatio = 4.0f/3.0f;
CGFloat camViewHeight = screenBounds.width * cameraAspectRatio;
CGFloat scale = screenBounds.height / camViewHeight;
picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, (screenBounds.height - camViewHeight) / 2.0);
picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(picker.cameraViewTransform, scale, scale);
```

update

```
OverlayView *overlay = [[OverlayView alloc]
                            initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    picker =
    [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    picker.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    picker.toolbarHidden = YES;

    // Device's screen size (ignoring rotation intentionally):
    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    float cameraAspectRatio = 4.0 / 3.0;
    float imageWidth = floorf(screenSize.width * cameraAspectRatio);
    float scale = ceilf((screenSize.height / imageWidth) * 10.0) / 10.0;





     picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 2, 2);
   picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;

    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRec = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(zoom:)];
    [overlay addGestureRecognizer:pinchRec];
    overlay.image =image;
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:picker animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS 10.2 fixes this issue! You can now use the `cameraViewTransform` property before presenting the camera again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I had the same problem earlier in IOS 9.3 also. Here is the code i used

```
//transform values for full screen support
#define CAMERA_TRANSFORM_X 1
#define CAMERA_TRANSFORM_Y 1.12412    

        if (IS_IPAD)
            CGAffineTransformScale(objImagePickerController.cameraViewTransform, CAMERA_TRANSFORM_X,  CAMERA_TRANSFORM_Y);
        else if (IS_IPHONE_5_Land||IS_IPHONE_4_Land||IS_IPHONE_6_Land||IS_IPHONE_6_PLUS_Land)
        {
            objImagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 2, 2);
        }
```

Hope this helps. For more help: [UIImagePickerController's cameraViewTransform is ignoring 'scaling' and 'translation' on iOS 10 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39124794/uiimagepickercontrollers-cameraviewtransform-is-ignoring-scaling-and-transla)

Comment: i have used your code but still not working @ Jamshed Alam

Comment: Did you use    picker.allowsEditing = NO when your init the camera ?