# Correct scaling a UIImagePickerController preview image depending on device orientation

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, crop, landscape

I have a `UIImagePickerController` to take photos. I know, e.g. from [UIImagePickerController doesn't fill screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674375/uiimagepickercontroller-doesnt-fill-screen/23625383#23625383) that the iPhone camera has a different aspect ration that the device screen, so it is necessary to crop the camera image to get a photo without black bars.

My problem is the following:

When I take a photo in portrait mode, the preview image is cropped vertically, so that the image fills the whole preview space:
[image]

However, when I take the photo in landscape mode, the preview image is not cropped, so that a black bar appears on top of the preview image:
[image]

I have read that I can scale the preview image using the `cameraViewTransform` property of the `UIImagePickerController`. But I had to set this property **before** I take the photo, at a time when I don't know in which orientation the user will take the photo.
So if I apply a zoom transform before I take the photo, the photo will be unnecessarily cropped on all sides in portrait mode, and right in landscape mode. If I do not apply the transfer, the photo is taken right in portrait mode, but has a black top bar in landscape mode.

So what is the right way to crop the photo right (minimum cropping, but without a black bar) in both orientations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/)... They say:

IMPORTANT
The `UIImagePickerController` class supports portrait mode only.

So one simply **must not use a `UIImagePickerController` in landscape mode**.