# Make image the same as camera view

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using `UIImagePickerController` for taking photo. For full size photo I am using this method

```
var cameraAspectRatio : CGFloat = 4.0 / 3.0;
var imageWidth = floorf(Float(screenSize.width * cameraAspectRatio));
var data = Float(screenSize.height)/imageWidth
var scale = CGFloat(ceilf((data * 10.0) / 10.0))

cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale)
```

but after capturing image, the view that I saw in camera layer is different with photo(photo takes more view in, so it is bigger)

I want to make a photo, and output photo the same scale and view, using the whole fullscreen overlay.
Can you advice some?

Comment: so I need the same image that i see in camera, but not full size

Comment: any chance you found a solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I took help from this link in one of my project: [UIImagePickerController doesn't fill screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674375/uiimagepickercontroller-doesnt-fill-screen)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I saw this answer, and used it to fill full screen, but there is another problem - view that I take photo is scaled, and image that I get isn't, so they are different

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to have the view delivering the video-preview not overscanning the screen, and being in the right aspect-ratio.

My *guess* would be that there is two place you have to have a look at:

1. `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`'s previewLayer-property.
2. Your `AVCaptureSession`'s sessionPreset

If the latter is of the type `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` your frame calculations seems OK (as this is in the-format 4:3), but double-check this bit.

The `previewLayer` should then be `AVLayerVideoGravityResize` as this fills the preview to fit inside the view you have resized properly.