# Translate does not work in UIImagePickerController.cameraViewTransform

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, transform

My app stopped working correctly with iOS 4.3. It uses a custom camera view overlay for the UIImagePickerController. And I want to adjust the size and origon of the camera preview view by set cameraViewTransform as CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation and CGAffineTransformScale, but the CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation seems to have no effect, However scale and rotate transforms work as expected. And the preview View is always in the center of the screen, I want to make the change.

I had try method as below, but does not work too.

[Scaled live iPhone Camera view in center, "CGAffineTransformTranslate" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042306/scaled-live-iphone-camera-view-in-center-cgaffinetransformtranslate-not-workin)

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(picker.cameraViewTransform, 0.5, 0.5);
picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(picker.cameraViewTransform, -100, -100);

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I am seeing this on my 4.3 iPhone, but not on the ones with 4.2 and older. So it is definitely a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just moving the picker frame to get this to work. check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9458688/791661